# Add an explicit module dependency to a org.hibernate without modifying its module.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

Is it possible to add Jboss `com.h2database.h2` module as a dependency of `org.hibernate` module without modifying the `module.xml` file but from a deployment.

I am getting this exception when deploying an application with hibernate as ORM:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @652c4193 (finder: local module finder @3c854dc9 (roots: C:\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules,C:\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]

Resulting in a:

> HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;